# SQL Server : after CHECKDB repair_allow_data_loss. Can I use update instead of a full restore to recover lost data?

Tags: sql-server

Background; I'm not a SQL Server pro, but I've worked with it for some time.

Just started in this company, db was not doing backups because checkdb was failing prior to automated backup. The newest backup file was 4 months old. I did a repair and lost data, but I knew the table and cluster of unique id's of the lost data. The 4 mo old backup contains the lost data and does not throw a flag on checkdb. Can I use an update statement to recover the data to the live db?

Something like:

```
UPDATE new
SET new.col1 = old.col1, new.col2 = old.col2...etc
FROM old
WHERE old.col1 NOT IN new.col1
```